# Can I force a monitor to switch input using batch/c++

Tags: c++, batch-file, monitor, vga

I have 2 graphics cards (an integrated Intel card, and an NVIDIA card), and both of them are connected to a single monitor (VGA / HDMI).

say somehow both of them have different outputs (I have a windows 7 and a VM, each of which is using one card).

Is there any command/API that I can send to the monitor so it can automatically switch its input from VGA to HDMI or the other way around?

Comment: Does your monitor have ability to recieve command from PC?

Comment: @Fumu7 well, sadly I do not know...is there anyway I can find this out? I'll try google its user mannual..

Answer (score 0):

No — there is no publicly documented, standard way of doing this.

(It's possible that some rare monitors may provide a way of doing this. I've never seen or heard of one, though, and it'd be proprietary to that monitor.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools that support this via DDC commands.

One example is https://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net/